# extract xml tag value from the file to Variable

Tags: ksh, xml

I Have a file. where I need to extract dataTemplate name. 
need a value in datalob=XXPFARCUDO_DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<dataTemplate name="XXPFARCUDO_DATA" description="Ctrole de cohnce des clits doeux et conteeux" Version="1.0">
 <parameters>
  <parameter name="P_SOCIETE"               dataType="character"/>
 </parameters>
.
.
.
.
</dataTemplate>
```

I have code but it is not working

```
filename='XXPFARCUDO_DATA.xml'
LOBCODE=$(sed -n 's:.*<dataTemplate name="\(.*\)" description=".*:\1:p' "${filename}")
echo " --> ${LOBCODE} "
```

it result is not correct

```
 --> XXPFARCUDO_DATA▒role de cohnce des clits doeux et conteeux" Version="1.0">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the XML is well formed, such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<dataTemplate name="XXPFARCUDO_DATA" description="Ctrole de cohnce des clits doeux et conteeux" Version="1.0">
  <parameters>
    <parameter name="P_SOCIETE" dataType="character"/>
  </parameters>
</dataTemplate>
```

You would get the value of the attribute `name` in the `dataTemplate` node through [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
LOBCODE=$( xml sel -t -v '/dataTemplate/@name' "$filename" )
```

XMLStarlet is sometimes installed as `xmlstarlet` rather than as `xml`.

Using `xmllint`:

```
LOBCODE=$( xmllint --xpath 'string(/dataTemplate/@name)' "$filename" )
```

---

Please, don't try to parse XML using `sed`. It is error prone and fragile.

Comment: If I use this LOBCODE=$( xmllint --xpath 'string(/dataTemplate/@name)' "$filename" )

Unknown option --xpath
 --> Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles ...
        Parse the XML files and output the result of the parsing
        --version : display the version of the XML library used
        --debug : dump a debug tree of the in-memory document
and more..... and for LOBCODE=$( xml sel -t -v '/dataTemplate/@name' "$filename" ) it gives LPX-00202: could not open "sel" (error 200)

Comment: @ArunGoWdA The first error comes from an older version of `xmllint`.  The second error comes from the fact that `xml` on your system is _not_ XMLStarlet but some other program. Try `xmlstarlet` (after making sure that the program is actually installed), or upgrade your `xmllint`.

Comment: ok i try and let you know

Comment: we cannot install the upgraded switch due to limitation. can you please to extarct using the string? Oracle suggests the same